# Text justification for Li's

Tags: html, css, list, word-wrap

I have a few Li items in a Ul, and I want to make it so the text doesn't wrap all the way to the blue bullet points. Anyone know how to do this. I've attached the code and an image. Thanks

```
<ul>
    <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i><b> text:</b>text </li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i><b> text</b>text </li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i><b>Text</b> text</li>
</ul>
```

**Screenshot**
[image]

Comment: You should probably include your CSS code, since that is most likely causing this. It looks like you have a custom bullet point for your `<ul>` so that is most likely what's causing it. Without the CSS code we can only guess what a solution would be.

Comment: You should probably use actual bullets (i.e. use `list-style-image` with your custom image) and then set list-style-position to `outside`.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add padding for `<li>` in css and also to add background image for that.

Try something similar to

```
ul.teamslink {
list-style-type:none;
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
ul.teamslink li {
background: url(../images/teamlistbg.png) 12px 5px no-repeat;
padding-left:30px;
margin-bottom:1px;
color:#363636;
}
```

Html

```
<ul class="teamslink">
   <li></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way.

```
li {

  margin-left: 25px;
  position: relative;

}

.fa-check {

background: url(yourtickimage.svg) no-repeat;
width 20px;
height: 20px;
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: -25px

}
```

Gouravs answer below is nice although you don't need the margin-right: .100em; and if you've used a gloabal reset make sure to add 1em margin-left back to the ul.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
 li:before {
     content: '✔';   
      margin-left: -1em; margin-right: .100em;
  }
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AeY2x/1/)**

I Hope you wanted to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Text wrapping in list items is usually caused by a "list-style-position: inside" (which is default in most browsers)
I think the problem should be solved by declaring:

```
li{
list-style-position: outside;
}
```

Or, if nescessary also:

```
li{
list-style-position: outside;
text-indent: 0em;
}
```

Good luck!